# React-Router v4 rendering wrong component but matching correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-routing, frontend, react-router-v4

I've got a sidebar with two buttons, 'test' and 'about'. Test (rocket icon) is rendered at '/test', and About (home icon) is rendered at '/'.

They're both located at the root of the app and are nested within a  component.

When I start at '/' and click the Link to="/test" it always loads the 'About' component, and when I check the props for the componentDidMount of 'About', the match object contains match data for "/test".

Only when I refresh does it render the proper component, 'Test', again. Any idea why this is happening?

AppRoutes.js:

```
export class AppRoutes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact path="/"
            render={(matchProps) => (
              <LazyLoad getComponent={() => import('pages/appPages/About')} {...matchProps} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/login"
            render={(matchProps) => (
              <LazyLoad getComponent={() => import('pages/appPages/Login')} {...matchProps} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/register"
            render={(matchProps) => (
              <LazyLoad getComponent={() => import('pages/appPages/Register')} {...matchProps} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/test"
            render={(matchProps) => (
              <LazyLoad getComponent={() => import('pages/appPages/Test')} {...matchProps} />
            )}
          />
...
```

AboutPage.js && TestPage.js (duplicates except for component name):

```
import React from 'react';

import SidebarContainer from 'containers/SidebarContainer';
import SidebarPageLayout from 'styles/SidebarPageLayout';

export const About = (props) => {
  console.log('About Loading: ', props);
  return (
    <SidebarPageLayout>
      <SidebarContainer />
      <div>About</div>
    </SidebarPageLayout>
  );
}

export default About;
```

SidebarContainer.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import _ from 'lodash';

import Sidebar from 'sidebar/Sidebar';
import HamburgerButton from 'sidebar/HamburgerButton';
import AboutButton from 'sidebar/AboutButton';
import ProfileButton from 'sidebar/ProfileButton';
import TestButton from 'sidebar/TestButton';

export class SidebarContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sidebarIsOpen: false,
      sidebarElements: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.authenticated) {
      this.setState({
        sidebarElements: _.concat(this.state.sidebarElements, HamburgerButton, ProfileButton, AboutButton, TestButton),
      });
    }
  }

  toggleSidebarIsOpenState = () => {
    this.setState({ sidebarIsOpen: !this.state.sidebarIsOpen });
  }

  render() {
    const { authenticated, sidebarIsOpen, sidebarElements} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar
          authenticated={authenticated}
          sidebarIsOpen={sidebarIsOpen}
          sidebarElements={_.isEmpty(sidebarElements) ? undefined: sidebarElements}
          toggleSidebarIsOpenState={this.toggleSidebarIsOpenState}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SidebarContainer.propTypes = {
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default SidebarContainer;
```

Sidebar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import SidebarStyles from '../styles/SidebarStyles';

export const Sidebar = (props) => {
  if (props && props.sidebarElements) {
    return (
      <SidebarStyles sidebarIsOpen={props.sidebarIsOpen}>
        {_.map(props.sidebarElements, (value, index) => {
          return React.createElement(
            value,
            {
              key: index,
              authenticated: props.authenticated,
              sidebarIsOpen: props.sidebarIsOpen,
              toggleSidebarIsOpenState: props.toggleSidebarIsOpenState,
            },
          );
        })}
      </SidebarStyles>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

Sidebar.propTypes = {
  authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  sidebarIsOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  sidebarElements: PropTypes.array,
  toggleSidebarIsOpenState: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Sidebar;
```

TestButton.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Icon from 'react-fontawesome';
import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

export const TestButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <Link to="/test">
      <Icon name='rocket' size='2x' />
    </Link>
  );
}

export default TestButton;
```

AboutButton.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Icon from 'react-fontawesome';
import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

export const AboutButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <Link to="/">
      <Icon name='home' size='2x' />
    </Link>
  );
}

export default AboutButton;
```

No refresh, just constant clicking on the '/test' route from the '/' route:

[image]

after refresh:

[image]

Edit:

Root components:

Edit:

store.js:

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose,
} from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import { rootReducer } from './rootReducers';
import { rootSaga } from './rootSagas';

// sagas
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

// dev-tools
const composeEnhancers = typeof window === 'object' && (
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ? (
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
  ) : compose
);

export function configureStore() {
  const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware,
  ];
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    {},
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
  );

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  return store;
}

export const store = configureStore();
```

index.js (root):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { store } from './store';
import AppContainer from 'containers/AppContainer';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContainer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

AppContainer:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { logout, verifyToken } from './actions';
import { selectAuthenticated, selectAuthenticating } from './selectors';
import AppRoutes from 'routes/AppRoutes';

export class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loaded: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
    if (token) {
      this.props.verifyToken(token, () => this.setState({ loaded: true }));
    } else {
      this.setState({ loaded: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loaded) {
      return (
        <AppRoutes
          authenticated={this.props.authenticated}
          authenticating={this.props.authenticating}
          logout={this.props.logout}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return <div>Loading ...</div>
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authenticated: selectAuthenticated(state),
    authenticating: selectAuthenticating(state),
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    verifyToken: (token = '', callback = false) => dispatch(verifyToken(token, callback)),
    logout: () => dispatch(logout()),
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer));
```

Edit 2 for LazyLoad:

services/LazyLoad/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export class LazyLoad extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      AsyncModule: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getComponent()  // getComponent={() => import('./someFile.js')}
      .then(module => module.default)
      .then(AsyncModule => this.setState({AsyncModule}))
  }

  render() {
    const { loader, ...childProps } = this.props;
    const { AsyncModule } = this.state;

    if (AsyncModule) {
      return <AsyncModule {...childProps} />;
    }

    if (loader) {
      const Loader = loader;
      return <Loader />;
    }

    return null;
  }
}

export default LazyLoad;
```

Comment: I was having a similar problem yesterday on my project. My <Router> had a wrapping child component <TopLayout> that was using redux and this was blocking the re-render. Fixed it by changing `connect(...)(TopLayout)` to `withRouter(connect(...)(TopLayout))` so it will re-render each time the route changes. More info here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter. You're not showing us your <Router> implementation, so I'm not sure it's the same problem.

Comment: This feels so much like the right answer and I want it to be true but it's still not working for me. I went over and wrapped every container and component that had a connect() call with withRouter and it's still giving me the bug.

Comment: This might be because of `LazyLoad`. Can you share the `LazyLoad` code?

Comment: edited to include it

Comment: @TomVanRompaey, Thanks! Your comment solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies with `LazyLoad` component. For both "/" or "test" paths, what `AppRoutes` component ultimately renders is a `LazyLoad` component. Because `Route` and `Switch` just conditionally render their children. However, React can't differentiate "/" `LazyLoad` component and "/test" `LazyLoad` component. So the first time it renders `LazyLoad` component and invokes the `componentDidMount`. But when route changes, React consider it as a prop change of previously rendered `LazyLoad` component. So it just invokes `componentWillReceiveProps` of previous `LazyLoad` component with new props instead of unmounting previous one and mount a new one. That's why it continuously show About component until refresh the page.

To solve this problem, if the `getComponent` prop has changed, we have to load the new module with new `getComponent` inside the `componentWillReceiveProps`. So we can modify the `LazyLoad` as follows which have a common method to load module and invoke it from both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` with correct props.

```
import React from 'react';

export class LazyLoad extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      AsyncModule: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.load(this.props);
  }

  load(props){
    this.setState({AsyncModule: null}
    props.getComponent()  // getComponent={() => import('./someFile.js')}
      .then(module => module.default)
      .then(AsyncModule => this.setState({AsyncModule}))
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.getComponent !== this.props.getComponent) {
      this.load(nextProps)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { loader, ...childProps } = this.props;
    const { AsyncModule } = this.state;

    if (AsyncModule) {
      return <AsyncModule {...childProps} />;
    }

    if (loader) {
      const Loader = loader;
      return <Loader />;
    }

    return null;
  }
}

export default LazyLoad;
```

Comment: @KyleTruong I'm glad that it helped you. I'll explain why when I get some time.

Comment: Thank you again, looking forward to it.

Comment: This answer really helped me today @TharakaWijebandara. Similar issue except I was seeing a route component rendered when leaving that route (rendering on leave) which caused some issues. Your answer helped me see that the previous route component was being rendered because the same <Loader /> was being re-used. Thank you.